# How to avoid loading symbols of windows dlls in remote debugging?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

When debugging with vs, it tries to load symbols for all dlls.
For some reason, this takes a long time in remote-debugging (although there are no symbols on the target machine).

How can I tell vs not to load symbols for system dlls?

Comment: Ok, obviously I posted the question at a bad datetime, since it has only 8 views in 6 hours (6 of which are mine...). So I wonder if this comment will make it visible again. Worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to Debug -> Options and Setting -> Symbols and specifying what modules you want symbols to be automatically loaded for. I'm not sure if that will prevent system dlls from loading though.

There's also a "Just my code" option under Debugging -> General that you might check.

Also, I'd suggest trying to remove all unused references. If you are working on a VB.Net project, this is as easy as opening the project properties and clicking on the unused references under the references tab. Usually there are several system dlls (System.Xml.Linq for example) that VS kindly assumes you'll need that are referenced. There's a good chance they aren't being used (for example, you're never using any of the Linq extension methods) that can be removed.

Comment: I only use native code, so the Debug -> Options and Setting -> Symbols did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any equivalent to this in VS 2008? It doesn't have the "Only specified modules" radio button/link.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have VS 2008 to look at... let us know if you find an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another place to check. 
Not in the current project but globally for Visual Studio:

```
Menu :
Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols
```